# Python sqlite, no more rows added after a thousand. No errors or warnings

Tags: python, sqlite

I am running a scraper which is extracting table entries from various pages and feeding it into a sqlite database. One of the tables is supposed to carry about five thousand entries, but the data is no longer being added in sqlite after a thousand rows without showing any errors of warnings.

The structure of my program:

```
  def start():
       ...
       ...
       get_info_from_page()
       ...

  def get_info_from page()
       ... 
       ...
       info = (id,info1,info2)
       cursor.execute("insert into infotable values (?,?,?)",info)
       connection.commit()
       ...
       ...
```

(The reason I am executing and committing inside get_info_from_page is because of a slow internet connection which caused frequent timeouts, and I don't want to lose any data already scraped.)

Answer (score 0):

On the problem - not enough data. Possible error in the code (check their counters in your code, possibly in obtaining the data from the page (structure changed).

For a slow Internet connection, I turned code in:

```
from urllib.error import URLError

try:
    YOUR CODE
except URLError:
    time.sleep(5) 
    continue
```

At least, the process does not break, and hung.

Comment: I began from where SQLite stopped accepting rows by creating a similar table in a new database file, and so far it has created 200 more rows as expected. I'll see if this one hits the limit on reaching 1000 rows as well.

Comment: Try to read data from the database, drive them into a python list and before adding page to check whether they are in this list. If they still will not be added, it's in the page or in the database.